# Jenkins Gerrit Trigger - "/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" is not a valid key file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ssh-keys, openssh, gerrit-trigger

I've installed Jenkins in an Ubuntu server by following the documentation from Jenkins Install [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/#debianubuntu) and I am trying to set up [Gerrit Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/gerrit-trigger/). While setting up *Administrative Settings* section the SSH Keyfile section always gives the error *"/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa" is not a valid key file.*

I've generated the ssh keys as the Jenkins user in the default location *"/var/lib/jenkins/"*

I've tried generating the keys with `ssh-keygen`, `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` and the keys are generated with and without a passphrase also as pem file but still shows as invalid key file.

The files are present in the *"/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/"* location

```
jenkins@jenkins:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 16
drwx------  2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Oct  9 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 17 jenkins jenkins 4096 Oct  9 14:18 ..
-rw-------  1 jenkins jenkins 2602 Oct  9 14:05 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins jenkins  569 Oct  9 14:05 id_rsa.pub
```

I didn't find any log entries regarding this in jenkins log file also not in the web portal System Log section.

Comment: have you looked in the file? is the format correct? have you tried using the keys to ssh into another pc with `ssh-copy-id` ?

Comment: Yes, the file content seems fine and I can ssh to gerrit server by `ssh -p 29418 -i /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa jenkins@gerrit-domain`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to generate the key with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: Well, that actually did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps worked for me.

1. Currently my Jenkins home directory is pointing to `/home/home_for_jenkins` .And I need to use a different BOT user to fetch the Gerrit events.
2. In order to achieve the above requirement, I have generated ssh keys for BOT user by using `ssh-keygen -m PEM` command and copied the generated keys to `/home/home_for_jenkins` folder and changed the permissions accordingly